# Problem setting the value or name attribute on a dynamically created radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, html, dom

I am trying to dynamically generate a group of radio button, however when I add a radiobutton with jQuery the name attribute is not set properly.

```
        var radioButtonInput = document.createElement("input")
        var groupId = groupNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
        var groupName = groupNodes[i].getAttribute("displayName");

        $(radioButtonInput).attr("type","radio");
        $(radioButtonInput).attr("name","radioGroup");
        $(radioButtonInput).attr("id", groupId);

        $("#meetingType h2").after(radioButtonInput);
```

The radio buttons are created correctly but the name attribute is not present. I've tried to use the html dom attribute .name but it generates the same result.

Comment: what is `.getAttribute("displayName")`

Comment: This works for me. How are you verifying the presence of the name attribute?

Comment: .getAttribute("displayName") is an attribute i'm getting from an xml document but this works just fine. I'm verifying the presence of the name attribute with firebug lite for IE. I have IE7, also the radio buttons should be mutually exclusive if the name property is set properly but they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var groupId = groupNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
var groupName = groupNodes[i].getAttribute("displayName");
var radioButtonInput = $("<input>", { "type" : "radio", "id" : groupId, "name" : "radioGroup"});

$("#meetingType h2").after(radioButtonInput);
```

where do you use groupName because here the input name will be "radioGroup" and not groupName

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the most straightforward way:

```
$("#meetingType h2").after('<input type="radio" id="' + groupNodes[i].id + '" name="' + groupNodes[i].getAttribute("displayName") + '" />');
```

If still no luck please elaborate on "name attribute is not present" - how can you tell that? How do you check?